# Laravel: use redirect outside Controller?

Tags: laravel, redirect, controller

I have a route

```
Route::get('/abc', function () {
    return view('common.abc');
});
```

When I access http://domain.com/abc it's work well.

And in Controller, I use

```
Redirect::to('/abc')
```

it's work well.

==> BUT, I need to **call redirect outside Controller** (Model, Lib etc....) How can I do that? I always get an error when call redirect outside the Controller.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @DoanTran: Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag as array

Comment: I dont see any errors when I call redirect inside a model. It works as usual [gist](https://gist.github.com/DoanTran/9fc408390a5129a6228d2f58322c89b6). Can you show more details about your code?

Answer (score 8):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

Redirect::to(url('blah-blah'))->send();
```

You can also use named routes with parameters like so:

```php
Redirect::route('route.name.here', ['foo' => 'bar'])->send();
```

If you are in a controller, you normally return the redirect. However, outside of a controller, you need to use `->send()` to tell it to "go now".

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: Edited to include more info. This should be the selected answer since it uses Laravel's built in methods and not a hack or workaround. The other answers here are just terrible advice... though, maybe `send()` wasn't around when this question was asked? I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should help.

```
abort(200, '', ['Location' => '/abc']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did small research and it seems it's impossible to use Laravel redirect in a `model()`, for example.

But you could redirect manually to URL:

```
$url = route('/abc');
header('Location: '.$url);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: `return \Redirect::route('abc');` doesn't work either?

Comment: And what error message do you see in Debugbar or logs?

Comment: Oh oh unfortunately, Header is not allowed at this project :(